# Interpreter and Datastructure for parsing (String) Equation

Tags: java, math, data-structures, interpreter, equation

I am looking for a interpreter and/or datastructure in Java that can handle strings like:

```
x^2+y^2+z^2 = 1"
```

and interprets it by `+`, `-`, `=` delimiters and later with other operations like `^`.

This is all for a 3D plotting project, so I am also looking for a tool that can isolate one of the varibles in such string/datastructure.

If you know of such a structure/intepreter/tool, or have any ideas how to implement this, I would love to hear your thoughts.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Expressions like that can be parsed using a [recursive descent parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser). The parser can be written directly, or if the grammar gets complex, with a parser generator such as [antlr](http://www.antlr.org/). The expression could be converted to an abstract syntax tree, or evaluated as it is being parsed.